# Generated column 'UserCode' cannot refer to auto-increment column. EfCore

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an account table that has ID auto-increment as true. Now I want to add Computed Column based on which. It can Add new value To the UserCode by the following Logic.

```
builder.Entity<Account>().Property(p => p.UserCode)
                .HasComputedColumnSql(@"CONCAT(CASE WHEN Role= 0 THEN 'ADM' 
                                                    WHEN Role = 1 then 'ADV' 
                                                    WHEN Role = 2 then 'INV' 
                                                    WHEN ROle = 3 then 'EMP' END,

                                        LPAD(ID, 8, '0'))");
```

Here is the Account Entity and DB set
`public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }`

When I am running the migration, It's working fine But when I am executing Update Database, I am getting the following error.
**Generated column 'UserCode' cannot refer to the auto-increment column.**

PS: I don't want to use any trigger or more than one update statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed in MySQL. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

> An AUTO_INCREMENT column cannot be used as a base column in a
> generated column definition.

This is likely due to such a column being a violation of 3NF and decided not to be supported when MySQL introduced generated columns. Generated columns need to work optionally as both virtual and stored values, which would cause a distinct "chicken & egg" scenario in the stored flavour.

Your options are <s>either to use a trigger on insert to populate a stored column dependent on the key, violating 3NF and introducing a possible data inconsistency between the Key and a column dependent on that key;</s> *Edit: Appears to be an illegal option in MySQL :)* Or compute this property as an unmapped property entirely within your entity.

For instance:

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int AccountId { get; set; } 

    public Roles Role { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserCode 
    {
        get 
        {
            switch(Role)
            {
                case Roles.Admin:
                    return $"ADM{AccountId:00000000}";
                case Roles.Advisor:
                    return $"ADV{AccountId:00000000}";
                case Roles.Invenstor:
                    return $"INV{AccountId:00000000}";
                case Roles.Employee:
                    return $"EMP{AccountId:00000000}";
                default:
                    return $"???{AccountId:00000000}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a trigger to change any columns based on the auto-increment values. A `BEFORE` trigger does not have access to the auto-increment value generated, and an `AFTER` trigger cannot change other columns in the table. The OP will have to do an extra UPDATE following their INSERT.

Comment: Thanks! I struck that out. MySQL's not my thing, and didn't think to check if Auto increment preceded the BEFORE trigger. Apparently you can use `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES ...` to get the auto-increment value for that table, but it's not 100% reliable, so not about to recommend it. :) Would have hoped that the ID was reserved and available as part of the BEFORE trigger values.

Comment: Querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the value creates a race condition. Two concurrent sessions could read the same value at the same time, and then try to insert the next value. There's a reason the auto-increment mechanism relies on a (brief) table lock internally, and operates outside of transaction scope.