# Using auto_increment id field value in other columns in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql 8.0.30.
I have an orders table which is defined as follows:

```
create table orders (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY, 
code varchar (64) NOT NULL, 
ord_num varchar(512) NOT NULL );
```

After inserting a rows, I would like to have it as follows:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | code | ord_num|
+----+------+-------+
|  1 | abc  | abc-1 |
|  2 | def  | def-2 |
+----+------+-------+
```

That is ord_num should have concatenation of code-id. I can achieve that by an update statement as follows:

```
update orders set ord_num = concat (code, '-', id ) where id = 2;
```

However, I would like to achieve that in the insert statemenet. For ex:

```
insert into orders (code, ord_num) values ("xyz", concat(code, '-', id));
```

This actually results in:

```
+----+------+-----------+
| id | code | ord_num   |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | abc  | abc-0     |
|  2 | def  | def-2     |
|  3 | xyz  | xyz-0     |
+----+------+-----------+
```

I know I can do this by starting a transaction, insert with some dummy value in ord_num, then updating it with the correct value before committing. I would prefer to do it in one insert statement, if possible?

Comment: I think your options are limited here, neither a generated column, nor a trigger can handle this (options explored in [this slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69183542/1048425)). You can create a view that sits over the table but this is probably more verbose than just repeating the concat operation when needed in T-SQL. Or as you say, you can have a procedure that does an insert and update in one transaction, but you're open to people inserting without the procedure

Comment: What I would say though is that this generated value appears to be more of a visual item rather than data, so it is potentially something that should reside in your presentation layer and not in the database itself. So if you have models on top of your database, considering having this property there instead

Comment: I know that is not a good way but just as an idea, creating a `trigger` after `Insert` and get the last id inserted. This could be a disaster if someone inserts data after your insert query. 
Another bad idea is before your `insert`, get the last ID and sum one value id+1. So if you get ID=23 you now your next ID is 24 (or not).

Comment: No. This is not for presentation layer. The ord_num column actually represents "order number" for the order and it follows certain structure as stipulated by the business. The column has to be inserted in an atomic transactions to maintain integrity. So, I would prefer not to use any triggers etc.

Comment: There is a solution. But it is complex - it uses a trigger and additional enumerating table which generates autoincrement values. `id` in your working table won't be autoincrement in this case. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74515455/10138734

Comment: @DúverCruz The technique with AFTER INSERT trigger which you describe cannot be realized on MySQL. The technique which uses MAX(id) will fail in concurrent environ.

Comment: What I meant was that if you are storing the two separate components (code and id) anyway, this new column is unlikely serve any integral purpose in your database, other than display or search purposes. Since this field can be generated based on existing columns you don't necessarily *need* this field stored it is a convenience issue rather than a necessity. As I say, you could create a view and query that whenever you need this concatenated field, but in terms of a single statement I don't think you have any clean options here

Comment: ' stipulated by the business' - I would push back on this.

Comment: @GarethD Yes, providing a view is an option. As this is tied to revenue, business is very sensitive about this. It needs some explanation and documentation. If there is an option to insert that would be the best.